# Not Saving Domain Object with Grails Searchable Plugin

Tags: grails, searchable

Is it possible to use the Searchable Plugin to create an index of objects and never actually save the objects to the database?

Answer (score 1):

I think so. If you never save the objects, then I think you can just call:

```
domainInstance.index()
```

But I've never tried it, so I'm not sure if it just indexes the one instance, or any instance of that class.

See here:
https://svn.codehaus.org/grails-plugins/grails-searchable/trunk/src/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/searchable/compass/domain/DynamicDomainMethodUtils.groovy

If you just want to save the object but just want to index manually, then set the following in your conf/Searchable.groovy config file:

```
mirrorChanges = false
bulkIndexOnStartup = false
```

See here: https://svn.codehaus.org/grails-plugins/grails-searchable/trunk/src/conf/Searchable.groovy